# How to create WebOs SmarTV App Using Angular8?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, webos, lg, smart-tv

I want to create an LG smart TV application using `Angular8`. I Have created an angular app using `CLI` but when I import this application on `WebOS IDE` it is not working. And if I create an app using `IDE` then I don't know how to install Angular on this application manually.

So **I want to create WebOS app with Angular8**

Comment: Can you explain what you did and didn't work?

Comment: @LingVu I have created an angular8 app using angular CLI then imported this app to WebOS Ide to run app on WebOS tv which did not work.

Comment: What kind of `didn't work`? Please more insights like how did you import, error outputs, logs, reproducable steps etc.

Comment: Otherwise it's like: I build a car and it didn't work, help...

Comment: Are you using the CLI that webOS recommends? Are you developing on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TOAST](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/toast)  is an open source Cordova plugin for developing TV Web applications, created by Samsung. TOAST enables you to create a multiple-platform solution for your TV Web application,. But you will get lot of extra functionalities to build a multiple-platform apps due the main point of TOAST is to act as a proxy between your app and the TV, so every operation in TOAST is translated to the correct system function. You can check the TOAST wiki to get a complete list of methods and its compatibility with the supported platforms (browser, LG webOS, Samsung Tizen, Samsung Legacy (orsay))

A more formal framework for Tizen would be CAPH:

CAPH is a Web UI framework for TV. Develop High Performance Web Application Easily and Quickly. CAPH consists of below modules.

Key Navigation

Scrollable List and Grid

UI Components : Button, Radio Button, Toggle Button, Checkbox, Input, Dialog, Context Menu, Dropdown Menu

Touch feature : Pan, Tap and Double Tap. (from CAPH 3.1)

Please find more info about CAPH [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/caph-30)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to transpile your code to ES5 using a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

[Here](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/web-api/supported-standard-web-api/) you can get more information about standard JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3 features supported in LG webOS versions.

Comment: I know all these things but the matter is I have created an app using HTML CSS and js now I want to create the same app using angular 8 .  so how can i do that